# Why JavaScript changes values of whole the array column?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a 2D array of certain dimensions - 26x2. I'm doing it with 2 for loops.
Then I try to change certain element but it changes whole the array column.

Can anybody explain why it happens?

```js
function convertTable() {
                var colsNum = 2;
                var rowsNum = 26;
                var rowCounter = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < colsNum; i++) {
                    rowCounter.push(0);
                }
                var counterArray = [];
                var colCounter = rowCounter;
                for (var i = 0; i < rowsNum; i++) {
                    counterArray.push(colCounter);
                }
                document.write(counterArray);
                document.write("<br>");
                counterArray[0][0] = 1;
                counterArray[0][1] = 2;
                counterArray[1][0] = 10;
                counterArray[1][1] = 20;
                document.write(counterArray);
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body onload="convertTable()"></body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are pushing the same `rowCounter`s into your array. Keep in mind that `rowCounter` is a *reference* to your array.

Comment: So `counterArray` is not a 2d array?

Comment: It is, but your rows are all referencing the same row.

Comment: Is there a way to assign not the refference to array but it's values?

Comment: I'll post an answer.

Comment: Are you sure? I was going to delete a question.. because it is too simple to fix..

Comment: You can leave the question here. It might help others out in the future.

Comment: Thanks @Derek朕會功夫

Comment: No problem! @Андрій Бойко

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < rowsNum; i++) {
    counterArray.push(colCounter);
}
```

What you are doing here is pushing the same reference to your row repeatedly, so your 2D array looks like this:

```
| ref#1 |
| ref#1 |             ref#1 = [0, 0, ..., 0]
   ...
| ref#1 |
```

What you actually want, however, is something like this:

```
| ref#1  |             ref#1  = [0, 0, ..., 0]
| ref#2  |             ref#2  = [0, 0, ..., 0]
   ...
| ref#26 |             ref#26 = [0, 0, ..., 0]
```

And therefore, you should create a new array before you push it in:

```
var colsNum = 2;
var rowsNum = 26;

var matrix = []
for(var row = 0; row < rowsNum; row++) {
    var rowArray = []
    for(var col = 0; col < colsNum; col++) {
        rowArray.push(0);
    }
    matrix.push(rowArray);
}
```